# Payoff value clarification - game theory

Tags: game-theory

[image]

Could someone please tell me why for the strategies $(H,H)$ and $(D,D)$, they use $\frac{v}{2}-k$ and $\frac{v}{2}-d$. Since if the animals get payoff $v$ and they hawk, they lose $k$, hence the payoff of both hawking is $v-k$? No? And similar logic for Dove.

Comment: "If both players choose $H$ then they split the resources" and similarly for $D$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist oh yes, this is right. I just thought it was something meant to do with $k > v/2$ and $d< v/2$ . So what was the point of defining $k$ and $d$ that way then?

Comment: $k>{v\over 2}$ makes $D$ the unique best response to $H$. This is the "interesting" case, otherwise $H$ would be dominant. $d<{v\over 2}$ makes $(D,D)$ Pareto efficient, but afaik usually $d=0$ is chosen anyway.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Evolutionary biologists define $k$ and $d$ that way because that’s how they end up with a simple game that seems to model the behaviour that they’re interested in studying. How else did you want them to model this situation?